# Slope without friction - circular motion problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, gravity

> An object of mass $m$ travels down a slope on earth without friction. At the bottom of the slope, what is the force exerted on the object by the ground?

My textbook says that this force cannot equal $m$ times $g$ because centripetal force is needed.

---

I don't understand how this is possible. It seems to me that the force exerted by the ground on the object is only dependent on mass and the gravitational constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ground exerts a normal force of $mg$ on an object that has no vertical acceleration - the object's weight is perfectly balanced by the normal force, so the object does not accelerate vertically.

Here, the object *does* have vertical acceleration, since it has non-zero vertical velocity when moving down the slope, and zero vertical velocity after it leaves the slope. Since the vertical velocity decreases, there must be a negative acceleration, and an net upward force. The downward force of gravity on the object is always $mg$, so the normal force provided by the ground must exceed $mg$ at some point to make the object stop moving vertically.

If the normal force of the flat ground remained exactly $mg$, there would be no net vertical force, and the object's vertical velocity would remain constant from the moment it left the incline. This would imply that the object moves downward through the floor at whatever speed it left the incline, which is obviously impossible.

Answer (score 2):

That the force acting by the floor on the object has to be greater than mere $mg$ can be shown with the following **idealization**:

[image: Centripetal force]

Imagine the very bottom of the slope to be a small circular arc with radius $R$. Assume also that the object enters the arc with velocity $v$. To keep the object at that circular path requires a centripetal force $F_c$:

$$F_c=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$

$F_c$ is essentially the force needed to make the object change direction.

So the total force becomes:

$$F=mg+\frac{mv^2}{R}=m\Big(g+\frac{v^2}{R}\Big)$$

Answer (score 1):

Newton's first law of motion is that an object moves at a constant velocity until a force acts on it. When an object is stationery on the ground, there is gravity acting on it, but it is equally balanced by the force exerted by the ground, so there is an equilibrium and that is why it doesn't move. Both the weight of the ball and the normal force by the ground would be *mg* , and so the *net* force would be 0.

In the case of a ball running down a slope, the ball is moving down with a certain velocity, and when it hits the bottom of the slope it changes direction i.e. it *decelerates* in the vertical direction, and accelerates in the horizontal direction. So there must be a difference between the force exerted by the ground and the force exerted by gravity, otherwise the direction wouldn't change. Since it decelerates in the downward direction, there must be a *net* force upwards, which has to be more than the downward force *mg* by gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Mg is the downward force of gravity.  The ground exerts an upward Normal force.  If the slope at the bottom can be described as part of a circle, then the resultant may be causing a centripetal acceleration.